# Performance of sum(1) vs count(1) for counting rows

Tags: sql-server

Is there any difference performance-wise between`select sum(1) from Products` and `select count(1) from Products`?

Comment: Nothing that you would ever notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both took same time on a very large table and when ran them together....came out with each having 50% cost:

[image]