# Get all rows along with duplicate column count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table, I want to write an optimized query:

```
Id   Name      Department
--------------------------------
 1   Ojas      Soft Engineer    
 2   Amy       Marketing        
 3   Aditya    Networking      
 4   Riya      Admin      
 5   Ojas      Manager      
 6   Riya      Receptionist
```

I need the output to be:

```
Id   Name      Department     Name repeat count
------------------------------------------------
 1   Ojas      Soft Engineer           2
 2   Amy       Marketing               1
 3   Aditya    Networking              1
 4   Riya      Admin                   2
 5   Ojas      Manager                 2
 6   Riya      Receptionist            2
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    Id, Name, Department, COUNT(*) as RepeatNameCount
FROM
    Email
GROUP BY
    Name
```

But I want every row to be returned. My problem is sometimes in grid only 10 rows will be returned but Number of Name repeated should be return for all available data

Comment: There are several ways you can do this. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Your attempt won't work because you have an aggregate but did not group by all the other columns. Look closely at your data and your query. Which value for Id should be returned for Ojas? And which Department? Notice that doesn't work. See the answer below from scaisEdge. It is one of the ways to solve this. But any solution will be similar at least conceptually.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is with the window function

```
Select *
      ,RepeatCnt = sum(1) over (partition by Name) 
 From Email
```

> **Full Disclosure:  I suspect scaisEdge's approach is more performatn**

Comment: WHy `sum(1)` instead of `count(*)`?

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Presumably, less typing.  I imagine that John might be something of a Puritan when it comes to programming constructs and wants one best way to do things.  If I'm right, he is probably really, really frustrated with SQL.  ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Am I that transparent?

Comment: @dnoeth To answer you question... no reason other than other than rolling off the fingers easier.   I even spent a few minutes looking for ANY justification {in this case}.   Nothing other than no difference...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104047/performance-of-sum1-vs-count1-for-counting-rows

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join on subquery with aggreated  result

```
  SELECT    a.Id, a.Name, a.Department, t.RepeatNameCount
  FROM     Email a
  INNER JOIN (
      select name, COUNT(*) as RepeatNameCount 
      from Email
      group by name 
  ) t = t.name = a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *window function* or `subquery`

```
select *,
        count(*) over (partition by name) RepeatNameCount  
from email e;
```

Or you may also use `subsquery`

```
select *,
        (select count(*) from email where name = e.name) RepeatNameCount  
from email e;
```

Answer (score 0):

select Id, Name, Department,
         (Select count(*) from email x where x.name = y.name group by x.name) as Repeat_Name_Count
from email y;